# How to make typescript support object destructuring with node v4.0.0?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I am using typescript with "es6":

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "amd",
        "target": "es6"
    }
}
```

So code like this:

```
var rect = {x: 0, y: 10, width: 15, height: 20};
var {x, y, width, height} = rect;
console.log(x, y, width, height);
async function a() {

}
```

will generate code like this:

```
var __awaiter = (a, b, c, d) => require("co").call(a, d);
var rect = { x: 0, y: 10, width: 15, height: 20 };
var { x, y, width, height } = rect;
console.log(x, y, width, height);
function a() {
    return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
    });
}
```

However, my node environment is "v4.0.0", it does not support:

```
var { x, y, width, height } = rect;
```

With "es5" generate:

```
var rect = { x: 0, y: 10, width: 15, height: 20 };
var x = rect.x, y = rect.y, width = rect.width, height = rect.height;
console.log(x, y, width, height);
// async function a() {
// }
```

But

```
error TS1311: Async functions are only available when targeting ECMAScript 6 and higher.
```

Any way to fix this problem?